# How can I see the output of my program in the Turbo C IDE?

Tags: c, windows, ide

How do I print `#include<conio.h>` in C

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
printf("#include<conio.h>");

}
```

How to get the output as

```
#include<conio.h>
```

**you have to put getch(); and press Ctrl+f9 instead of alt+f5**

Comment: I think you didn't need to do anything. It just works, isn't it? Does it compile, what output do you get?

Comment: @ Artelius and vodkhang i get a  blank screen

Comment: @subanki: "i get a blank screen" Is it switched on?

Comment: Seriously! Which compiler are you using? Have you tried stepping through with the debugger?

Comment: Note: `conio.h` is not, and never has been, a valid ANSI C++ header. Use it at your own risk.

Comment: @Johnsyweb obviously my monitor is switched on and by the way i am using Turbo C compiler by Borland

Comment: @subanki : Can you tell how are you compiling and what is the name of the executable?

Comment: @Praveen i just type the above code and press alt+F5 to compile and run

Comment: If it's Borland Turbo C, then press Ctrl+F9, after adding "getch();" after calling "printf".

Comment: @Johnsyweb the compiler says evrything is correct but is till get no output

Comment: @archangel ur method works , hurray , thanks friends

Comment: Then why was the compiler not showing ouput when alt+f5 was pressed , it just compiles and runs at the same time ...wat difference did ctrl+f9 make

Comment: at+f5 doesn't compile and run your program, that is the job of ctrl+f9. alt+f5 only shows the output window. To compile, you will have to press alt+f9. To Compile and Run, you will have to press ctrl+f9.

Comment: @Archangel i think u r right, my teacher always go wrong :D

Comment: -1 because this is not at all about what the headline is claiming to be and tagged completely wrong. It is about a specific IDE and what buttons will convince it to compile the source.

Comment: @jens i think the question is perfect according to my doubts

Comment: @subanki I agree with Jens - the title should be "How can I see the output of my program in the Turbo C IDE?" or something similar. That might get you some more upvotes and also be more likely to help people with a similar problem find your question/solution.

Comment: @ Matt Curtia, if u all say so then i will edit the post

Comment: hey upvote it i edited the post as u people asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to do anything else. You have written the solution yourself. All you have to do is just `Compile` and `Run`......... :)

Comment: If you get a blank screen, then the problem is probably in somewhere else. The characters you are printing are perfectly valid to be printed using printf function in C. You don't have to add any escape characters or anything else. The problem is probably in your IDE settings or somewhere else. Can you print anything other than that? Try printing "Hello World" and see if it prints.

Comment: try removing the "conio.h" header, because it is not in ANSI C standard specification. Also have main return integer rather than void, write "void" as argument to the main, and return "0" from main. See if that works. Also, could you tell us which IDE/Compiler you are using?

Comment: then try adding a "getch();" after calling "printf" and see what is exactly happening here. Also try to debug the program.

Comment: @subanki: Check out my answer ---- I think you're problem's with the IDE, not the code.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a great confusion between the GCC(GNU Compiler Collection) and turbo c compilers.

In turbo C compilers the output will be stored separately in an output pane which can be viewed by pressing *alt+F5*.

In order to view the output while compiling you need to get an input from the output page so that the page exits only after typing an input.

This can be simply achieved by using a function called `getch();` which is obtained from the *conio.h* library.

Hence **insert a  `getch();` function after all the `printf` statements and press `ctrl+F9`.**
Now the program should exit only after giving an input.

NOTE: - The output page might be displayed for other programs which contain a *scanf* statement so that you can give an input on the output page.But even then you can't to see the output produced by the printf statements after the scanf by pressing Ctrl+F9.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running it from an IDE, you might need to look at the output console or something, and maybe it closes when your program quits before you get a chance to see what it has printed.

If you are running it from the command line, maybe (because it doesn't print a newline after the string) your prompt is clobbering the output.

Comment: assuming u r right , how to make it display the output for a longer time, i am using borland turbo C

Comment: Looks like (from your question amendment) I was right - it was printing after all, and the issue was (presumably) your IDE closing the output window too quickly. Feel free to mark this answer as "accepted" :)

Comment: I think Matt is right (he often is). If you run your executable from the command-line, the output should persist.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember Turbo C++ right (could be the same), you need to go to the `Output` window to see the result. So go to `Window` on the menu bar and select `Output` --- you should see your string there.

If that doesn't work add `getch();` to the end of your program. This will ensure that the program will wait for a keystroke from the user before exit.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me, but I suppose it's remotely possible that your STDOUT stream is not being flushed automatically. Try adding

```
fflush(stdout);
```

after the `printf`.

Comment: `stdout` should be flushed automatically at program termination.

Comment: Yeah, I'd have thought so too - and it is for me. Just throwing out the only possibility I can think of, based on the info given.

Comment: fflush(stdout); gives me a more darker blank screen, not working

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the shell will overwrite the last printed line if it doesn't end in a newline; try adding a `\n` to the end of the printf

Answer (score 0):

What if you replace the 'printf' call with

```
fprintf(stderr, "#include<conio.h>");
```

Or, try this:

```
_cprintf("#include<conio.h>");
```

Any luck?